# Uniqueness of $0$

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation

I am just a high school student. So, I don't know much about higer mathematics. But a question has come to my mind.

**Question:**

$$0 = 0^{n-(n-1) } = \frac {0^{n}}{0^{n-1}} = \frac {0}{0}$$

But $\frac {0}{0}$ is undefined. So, this means $0$ is undefined. But this is totally wrong.

I want to know are there any axioms, theorems or arguments claiming that it's wrong?

Comment: The reason is as simple as the exponent properties you're referencing only being ensured to hold for positive bases. Once you try to extend to nonpositive numbers, things may break.

Comment: High school gives you formulas without stating where they apply. Sometimes without justification. Sometimes they're just wrong (derivative zero implies minimum, maximum or inflection point, n equations in n unknowns). :(

Comment: @PrincessEev Can I get examples of it?

Comment: note that the "undefinition" of $\frac 00$ is rather understood as its value is context dependent, or it can take any value (like a joker in a card game), in particular $0$ or $1$ or $2.46$ or whatever. so in a sense this is not a contradiction, it can happen that it is zero.

Comment: @zwim that's not really accurate, $\frac{0}{0}$ is simply undefined, that is, it has not been defined. It cannot "take any value" because it's not a number, it's a meaningless string of symbols. It's a good idea to distinguish this from statements like "$\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate form", because that's not a statement about the expression $\frac{0}{0}$ itself (which, again, is meaningless) but about the behavior of limits of fractions when the numerator and denominator are both functions that approach zero in the limit.

Comment: You should try to understand the definition of symbol $a^b$ when $b$ is an integer and check the exponent laws for such definition.

Comment: Rules do not apply to numbers for where they are not defined.  $0^k; k \le 0$ is undefined so any rule that refers to $b^k; k \le 0$ will not apply to $0$.  So claiming that $a^{k-j} = a^k\cdot a^{-j}$ simply does not apply. (In a way this is like the rule $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a \sqrt b$.  As $\sqrt{k}; k< 0$ is undefined (in real number based arithmetic) the rule simply does not apply to $\sqrt{6} = \sqrt{(-2)\cdot (-3)} =\sqrt{-2}\sqrt{-3}$ and we are just writing down symbols with no meaning.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks to everyone. I just forgot writing $a ≠ 0$ (when getting $a^{n}$) for solving exponential problems. That was a random question in my mind that I asked without thinking a little

Comment: "Can I get examples of it? "  Well the most obvious break is the one you discovered.  $0^{-k} = \frac 1{0^k}$ is a big monkey wrench.   Another is $b^{p} = \sqrt[k] {b^m}=\sqrt[k]b^m$ when $p = \frac mk$ leads to problems with $p = \frac 32=\frac 64$ so $(-16)^{\frac 32} = \sqrt{-16}^3$ is undefined and $(-16)^{\frac 64} = \sqrt[4]{(-16)^6}=\sqrt[4]{16^6}=\sqrt[4]{4^{12}}=4^3=64$.